# how to specify a specific folder to check?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a code that checks for the presence of .json

```
 csvDirectories.forEach(directory => {
    fs.readdirSync(directory).forEach(file => {
      const fullFileName = path.join(directory, file)
      const extName = path.extname(fullFileName)
      const baseName = path.posix.basename(file, extName)
      if (extName === '.csv') {
        const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(fullFileName, 'utf8')
        if (languages.indexOf(baseName) === -1) {
          languages.push(baseName)
        }
        console.debug(`Processing translation file: ${fullFileName}`)
        messages[baseName] = Object.assign(messages[baseName] ? messages[baseName] : {}, convertToObject(dsv.parseRows(fileContent)))
      }  
      if (extName === '.json') { 
        const fullFileName = path.resolve(directory, file)
        console.log (fullFileName, "fullFileName")
        const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(fullFileName, 'utf8')
        console.log (fileContent, "fileContent")
      }    
    })
```

}) 
const fullFileName checks all folders. I need my if to check only one specific folder

Comment: Why do you think fullFileName > checks all folder? It's just a absolute path to you file

Comment: We may be able to help you better if you [edit] your question to show the code right before and after the `if() {}` block you already showed.

Comment: how to make it take json only from a specific folder